# SBT dependsOn AutoPlugin

Tags: sbt

Why when I do `sbt compile` it doesn't print `Hello`?

```scala
// build.sbt
enablePlugins(Hello)
```

```scala
// project/Hello.scala
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object Hello extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport extends AnyRef {
    lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("Says hello")
  }
  import autoImport._

  override val projectSettings = Seq(
    hello := {
      streams.value.log.info("Hello")
    },
    compile in Compile := (compile in Compile).dependsOn(hello).value
  )
```

Cheers

Comment: This is the behavior I'd expect, since you added a dependency on `hello` from `compile`. Is there a way you could clarify your question?

Comment: I did `compile` depends on `hello`. Therefore `compile` should run `hello` as it depends on it. Also if I do add the `Hello.projectSettings` explicitly in `build.sbt` it would work.

Comment: Sorry I just saw that I wrote "does" instead of "doesn't"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/463761/dale-wijnand:

> The problem is that you're defining compile in Compile which then gets
>   over-written by JvmPlugin.
>   To do what you want you need to make your
>   AutoPlugin require the JvmPlugin:
>
> ```
> object Hello extends AutoPlugin {
>   override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
>
>   // etc
> }
> ```